# math to mysql query

Tags: mysql, math, sum

Is this possible in mysql query?

```
x = ∑x – ∑(x-1)
```

I want to calculate all hours in my table, the output should be like this[image]

03-Jul-16

```
1523 -> is all total in 1-Jul-16 until 3-Jul-16
```

10-Jul-16

```
56 -> is total in 1-Jul-16 until 10-Jul-16 subtract all total in 1-Jul-16 until 3-Jul-16
```

17-jul-16

```
2726 -> is total in 1-jul-16 until 17-jul-16 subtract all total in 1-jul-16 until 10-jul-16
```

24-jul-16

```
2218 -> is total in 1-jul-16 until 24-jul-16 subtract all total in 1-jul-16 until 17-jul-16
```

31-jul-16

```
2834 -> is total in 1-jul-16 until 31-jul-16 subtract all total in 1-jul-16 until 24-jul-16
```

Please advise me, thanks

Comment: possible but different way show your data

Comment: Could you show me the example @knowledge.... ?

Comment: Show me your sample data  then i will tell you